# Beginner regexp case, simple match

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a pregmatch pattern which applies to:

```
http://site.local/app/**/admin
```

text. I created something, which looks good, but it also pass the

```
http://site.local/app/vf/adming
```

what I dont want to. The basically created pattern:

```
preg_match('/http:\/\/site.local\/app\/.*\\/admin/', $siteUrl)
```

how should it be corrected?

Btw: operators/admins, I created this thread previously and since then that account is disabled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139579/i-need-a-regexp Now that you see, I really tried it hard, may I get that account back? If not, I understand

Comment: so may I get my old account promissing that I dont ask anything stupid no more?

Comment: As an aside, I use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rext/ to test regular expressions (a Firefox) plugin. Start off with the complete regex that does not work. Start deleting from the end until it matches. This will locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ^ and $ to "tell" regex the start and end of your pattern.

```
preg_match('/^http:\/\/site.local\/app\/(.*)\/admin$/', 'http://site.local/app/abcd/admin');
preg_match('/^http:\/\/site.local\/app\/(.*)\/admin$/', 'http://site.local/app/abcd/admins');
```

Comment: you know, you can use different delimiters for regexp. This would be more readable: `|^http://site.local/app/(.*)/admin$|i`, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

**[a-zA-Z]** only letters and **{1,5}** from 1 to 5 length. If you to allow numbers just change it to **[a-zA-Z0-9]**

```
$site = 'http://site.local/app/at/admin';

if(preg_match('/^http:\/\/site.local\/app\/[a-zA-Z]{1,5}\/admin$/', $site)){
    echo 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is that `.*` matches all characters where you actually want to match two *.

```
/^http:\/\/site.local\/app\/[\*]{2}\\/admin$/
```

Should do it...

Edit: To exlpain myself to the person who marked down.

The asker said he wanted a preg_match to match the

> text

```
http://site.local/app/**/admin
```

I did just that. How can you mark me down for understanding English?

But to statisfy the asker cos he did mean any chars and any number of chars between app and admin here is the amended version:

```
/^http:\/\/site.local\/app\/.*\\/admin$/
```

Comment: Mark downer can you explain your reason?

Comment: thats OK, it can be anything, not just 2 characters. And the question maker cant vote a post daun :)

Comment: Ah it's cos you don't have the rep to be able to do it yet :) but I have amended the answer so I show what you actually meant. I read it differently because I'm English :(